# Dynamically appended child has CSS ignored

Tags: polymer

I have seen this question asked here, as well as on Polymer's GitHub, none of the answers works for me.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/1tGHXTsFlXeNnq3hCb0P?p=preview

Index.html has app-element in body.

```
<head>
  <script src="https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="app.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bootstrap.html">
</head>

<body>
  <app-element></app-element>
</body>

</html>
```

app.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="page-one.html">
<dom-module id="app-element">

  <template>
    <style>

    </style>
    <div id="container">

    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "app-element",
      ready: function() {
        window.app = this;
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Index.html links bootstrap.html where page-one is declared.

```
<link rel="import" href="page-one.html">
<page-one></page-one>
```

page-one has page-base element with two content items added. Second item has class='foo' which should render red background, but it doesn't.

```
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="page-base.html">
<dom-module id="page-one">

  <template>
    <!-- scoped CSS for this element -->
    <style>
      .foo {
        background-color: red;
      }
    </style>
    <div>
      <page-base>
        <div>One</div>
        <div class="foo">Two</div>
      </page-base>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "page-one",
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

page-base adds itself to app-element after 'WebComponentsReady'.

```
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="page-base">

  <template>
    <!-- scoped CSS for this element -->
    <style>

    </style>
    <div>
      <content></content>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
          is: "page-base",
          created: function() {
            var self = this;
            window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
                Polymer.dom(window.app.$.container).appendChild(self);
                Polymer.dom.flush();
              });
            }
          });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

When page-one is added to app-element declaratively everything works fine.

Also, if I move .foo{} to app-element's style it works even when page is added programatically.

Does anyone know what's going on?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, figured it out. It should be page-one adding itself to app-element and not page-base.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to abuse Polymer into 'inheritance', like me, here is a solution http://plnkr.co/edit/PI4xPDsQ6RfCOYq3g3sM?p=preview.

Pay attention to this line in page-base:

```
Polymer.dom(window.app.$.container).appendChild(self.dataHost);
```